# Would Access-Control-Allow-Headers: foo-* allow request headers foo-1 and foo-2?

Tags: cors, wildcard, request-headers

F.e.,

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-company-*
```

instead of listing:

```
x-company-1

x-company-2
```

....
to include any possible future `x-company-*` headers?

Answer (score -1):

No, at least not directly. According to [the Fetch Standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org), the only legal wildcard in the following CORS response headers,

- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`,
- `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`,
- `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`,
- `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`,

is `*` by itself (and [only for anonymous access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards)); see the [relevant section](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-new-header-syntax) of the Fetch standard.

You could list `x-company-*` in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` but doing so would only allow request headers whose names are case-insensitive matches for `x-company-*`. Neither `x-company-1` nor `x-company-2` would be allowed.

That said, perhaps you can find a CORS-middleware library that lets its users to specify allowed request headers as patterns. I don't know of any such library.